# Do NOT hide soft keyboard while tapping controls in WP

Tags: c#, button, windows-phone-8, cursor, windows-phone-8.1

I have this piece of code for button in my Windows Phone 8.1 Store App project (not the Silverlight):

```
private void CursorRightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(QueryTextBox.Text)) return;
        QueryTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard); //also i tried FocusState.Pointer
        QueryTextBox.Select((TextBox.SelectionStart + 1) % (TextBox.Text.Length + 1), 0);
    }
```

As you can see, I am tring to move cursor to right in text programmatically and the problem is that it hides soft keyboard and then shows it again after tapping button. I need to have keyboard on while tapping this button.

I tried to tinker with Focus() methods for sender and TextBox objects but I couldn't find any possible solution.

So the question is, how do you force keyboard not to loose focus/not to hide while tapping on controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out with Sajeetharans help that I need to set IsTabStop value on controls to false. Then keyboard will stay there. I did it in constructor of my page like this

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CursorLeftButton.IsTabStop = false;
    CursorRightButton.IsTabStop = false;
}
```

and my button method

```
private void CursorRightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox.Text)) return;
    TextBox.Select((TextBox.SelectionStart + 1) % (TextBox.Text.Length + 1), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a loaded event to your container say grid,

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.IsTabStop = true;
    set focus on the control , say a textblock
    Txtblock1.Focus();
}
```

[How To Programmatically Dismiss the SIP (keyboard)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/07/02/programmatically-dismiss-the-sip-keyboard-in-windows-phone-silverlight-app.aspx)

Comment: Setting IsTabStop property to false on those buttons did the trick!

Comment: @KarelĐrakenusPrchal can u mark it as answer if if has helped you

Comment: Sure, I already did. However, I just want to tell you that in Windows Phone 8.1 method Focus() is defined [little different.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161.aspx)